# Error in R: Unable to open connection to X11

Tags: command-line, x11

I just set up a fedora distribution on my computer and am slowly trying to learn how to work from the command line. I was testing `R` which went fine, except for some reason when I tried again I suddenly seem to be unable to draw plots. I get the error:

```
> x = 1:5
> y = x^2
> plot(x,y)
No protocol specified
Error in X11(d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, d$gamma, d$colortype,  : 
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

and when I check the capabilities I see that `X11` is `FALSE`:

```
> capabilities()
No protocol specified
    jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE 
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
```

Although I know nothing about whether those are connected or not it seems X11 should be on?

Everywhere I searched for this people seemed to have this problem when working over an ssh connection (I haven't yet taken a look at what that is exactly :$).

I hope someone who knows what this problem is about could be so nice to explain the problem to me and suggest a solution.

Comment: Before starting R can you post output of `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: This command yields ´:0´

Comment: How about from R: `Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")`

Comment: hmm, this only gives me `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"DISPLAY"'`

Comment: Do this: `Sys.getenv(DISPLAY)` or this: `Sys.getenv('DISPLAY')` or `Sys.getenv(c("DISPLAY"))`

Comment: oops, it seems I didn't read all the comment. Ok, from R I get `[1] ":0.0"`

Comment: (although last comment was after I tried the posted solution). Without it I get `[1] ":0"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many threads elsewhere related to Cairo package.

[One of them](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.debian/1321)  mentions the change in X11 type but most of them state that R doesn't know what the display is and suggest doing:

```
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")
```

or, on older systems,

```
Sys.putenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither this solution, or the one mentioned in the other thread seem to fix this. :/ My package also insists on me using Sys.setenv instead of putenv.. don't know if hte new command is different?

Comment: `Sys.putenv` is deprecated in favor of `Sys.setenv`

Comment: This worked the next time I tried to use this :). Must have been something strange with the last session

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any local X server, you can install the virtual framebuffer X11 server like [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710952/535203):

```
apt-get install xvfb xauth xfonts-base
```

Then you can start a new instance like [said here](https://gist.github.com/jterrace/2911875):

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1960x2000x24 &
```

Then if your R is compiled with `with-x` configuration option (enabled by default), you should have X11 capability, and you just have to declare this in R:

```
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0")
```